# How much reputation have I awarded/lost/given away due to bounties?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, data-explorer

Is there a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query for how much reputation I have given away due to bounties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it is available on your user profile page under "bounties", e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15055/claudiu?tab=bounties&sort=offered .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a query available: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/254965/total-bounty-amount-offered-by-user